# Overwrite Azure Function Table Store row with output

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-functions

I have an **Azure PowerShell Function** that queries API Management analytics for a list of API's, and then outputs to a Table Store table via a **Function integration**.

A row is created for each API, with the **PartitionKey** being the name of the API and the **RowKey** being the date which the analytics are from.

This leads to an error should analytics for an API be requested more than once per day. At this point, **Function** exectution fails with a status of **500 Internal Server Error** and I'm presented with the following error -

> Error while handling parameter _binder after function returned: -> The specified entity already exists.

While I plan to run the Function on a schedule, thus avoiding this issue most of the time, it would be better to have a solution in place, with the ideal scenario being to overwrite an existing entry. Is this possible?

```
$apiIds.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object {
    $analytic = $_.Value | Get-ApiManagementAnalytics -Context $context -StartDate $startDate -EndDate $endDate -AccessToken
    $tableRow = $analytic.value
    $tableRow | Add-Member -NotePropertyName PartitionKey -NotePropertyValue $tableRow.name
    $tableRow | Add-Member -NotePropertyName RowKey -NotePropertyValue ((Get-Date).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"))
    $tableRows += $tableRow
}
$tableRows | ConvertTo-Json | Out-File -Encoding UTF8 $outputTable
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe what you are looking for is [TableOperation.InsertOrReplace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.table.tableoperation.insertorreplace?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=azure-dotnet)

This inserts the given entity into a table if the entity **does not exist**; if the entity **does exist** then its contents are replaced with the provided entity.

Comment: A valid solution, but I'm looking to be able to do this via the Function integration, as opposed to having to make my own connection to the Table Store.  Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, do you mind elaborating a bit more? Don't quite understand exactly what you would like to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Pls see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55527201

```
public string ETag { get; } = "*";
```